# Sqlite query to find all rows where a particular column field value lies in input string

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I got a scenario where I have to find all rows in Android SQLite db, where a particular column field value lies in the input string. For example, 
Input string:

```
I am not done yet, I can’t call it a day I need to work more for couple of hours.
```

Now my table in SQLite(Android) has a column called **Title**

I need to find all rows whose **Title** column  field values lies in above input string. Basically I want following rows 
where the full **Title** string is like one of below

1. call it a day
2. am not done yet

I want to know if it is possible using a single query in sqlite Android or not. What I know is LIKE query work on opposite manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your table contains a column `title` which has titles that you want to match in the given string, you can do concatenation with `%` to use `LIKE`

```
select *
from your_table
where 'your input string here' like '%' || title || '%'
```

Comment: Above is what I wanted. Thanks